# Web service provider routing

Tags: web-services, location, wcf-routing

I am looking to implement a service (web/windows, .net) that maintains a list of available services and can provide an endpoint based on the nature or type of request. The requester can then pass the actual work request to the provided endpoint. The actual work requests can contain very large chunks (from 10MB up to and possibly exceeding a GB) of data.

WCF routing services sounds like a perfect fit, but turns out not to be because the it requires the actual work request to pass through it, creating a bottleneck at the routing service (the whole point is to get a system to be able to scale out). If I had smaller messages, WCF routing would be a no brainer.

Is there anything out there that fits the bill? Preferably .NET/windows based?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean because the requests block for work?

Do could use `OneWay` `OperationContract` to create async services so as to not block the request pool.

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IMyContract
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
   void DoWork()
}
```

**Update**

I think understand your question better now, you are looking to distribute load to different servers to avoid request bottle necks due to heavy traffic load (preferably distributed based on content).

I'd say that `MVC Routing` is indeed ideal for this. One of the features that you can leverage is the fall over functionality. You can actually define multiple backup endpoints, and in the case where one fails, it will automatically move over to the next. There's a good introduction to how this works [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-40-The-New-WCF-Routing-Service).

There's also a good article here that talks about load balancing with WCF using the same principles. It provides 2 solutions for a [round robin filter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/routingrules/archive/2010/04/14/load-balancing-at-the-routing-service.aspx) implementation that allows you to load balance the service requests (even though at the begin he says his general answer to whether it supports load balancing is no for implementation reasons).

If you are worried about all requests routing via the one server and still becoming a bottle neck, then think of web load balancers. It's the same scenario. Sitting in the middle forwarding packets doesn't require much work, and they have no problem handling huge volumes of traffic. I don't think this is an issue IMO.

Comment: Not because they explicitly block for work, but because the server doing the routing will have to handle the entire content of large messages. At peak times, this is a ridiculous amount of data and number of requests.